# name 'newList' is not defined

Tags: python

So I am making a python game and I am trying to implement a save/load system. I have the save part down however the load function that I made isn't working. When I assign cPickle.load to a new list it isn't registering.

```
def save():
    file = open('save.txt', 'wb')
    cPickle.dump(GameState, file)
    file.close()

def load():
    inFile = open('save.txt', 'rb')
    newList = cPickle.load(inFile)
    inFile.close()
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to return your list in `load`:

```
def load():
    inFile = open('save.txt', 'rb')
    newList = cPickle.load(inFile)
    inFile.close()
    return newList
```

Note that a more Pythonic to load your file is:

```
def load(name_of_your_saved_file):
    with open(name_of_your_saved_file, 'rb') as inFile:
        newList = cPickle.load(inFile)
    return newList
```

Here, we use what is called a context in Python (the `with...as` statement), quite useful to make sure your file is automatically called. It's also a good idea not to hard-code the name of your file in the function, but pass it as an argument.

When you call your `load` function, you will get what you put in your pickle, a `GameState` in your case.

```
game_state_loaded = load('save.txt')
```

Comment: You should also mention how the function would be used `newList = load()`

Comment: @finaris: How are you calling the `load()` function? You need to do `newList = load()`. (Note that the name `newList` within the function has nothing to do with the name `newList = load()`: you could use a different name for each.

Comment: Yeah the list is now working, I forgot to call the load function and assign it to the list